# Bash: stat with variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

We can find the size of the file by the following command

```
filesize=$(stat --format=%s first.txt)
```

Now my question is that how can I use this with a variable i.e I want to replace the first.txt with a file.

Comment: Literally just use a variable instead of `first.txt`.

Comment: Could you show what you were trying (before asking this question), and what error you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the variable and use it...

```
filename=first.txt
filesize=$(stat --format=%s "$filename")
```

Comment: Needs quoting. `"$filename"`, not `$filename`; otherwise, this won't work with filenames with spaces, filenames with literal glob characters in their names when legitimate expansions exist, etc.

Comment: works without quoting unless there are spaces or other special characters in the filenames.  But you're right, it would be better. I'll edit it.

Comment: What defines a "special character" isn't constant -- **any** character can impact string-splitting if `IFS` is set to a non-default value.

Comment: Following robust practices, moreover, is important even when you *think* that unusual conditions can't/won't happen -- I've seen TB of backups deleted because (1) someone didn't quote their expansions in a shell script, and (2) a new process writing to an archival directory had a buffer overflow that put junk into a filename.

Comment: :-) They're going to have to pay me a lot more than they are if they want me to protect their whole backup scheme with a 12-second-typed-in answer to help someone starting with shell... :-)